# Поочередное выполнение php-скриптов в cron

Tags: php, linux, cron

Есть два php-скрипта. Необходимо запустить их поочередно, то есть пока не закончится первый скрипт, не выполнять второй. Можно ли так сделать в Debian Linux? Как сделать это в `cron`-е?

У меня первый скрипт работает в 1 ночи, второй скрипт выполняется в 2 часа ночи.

Comment: я отредактировал вопрос, сделав его более однозначным - если вдруг я переврал то, что на самом деле хотел спросить автор, прошу автора самостоятельно внести в него правки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command1 && command2` не то, что Вы ищете? `command2` будет выполнен только после успешного выполнения `command1`. если нужно не "после успешного", а "после любого результата", то `command1 || true && command2`.

Comment: 0 1 * * *    /usr/bin/flock -n /tmp/eshop-product-import.lock -c "cd /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/ && /usr/bin/php bitrix/1c_exchange_metrika_fon_import.php&&/usr/bin/php bitrix/1c_exchange_metrika_fon_offers.php   >> /tmp/eshop-product-import.log 2>&1"

Comment: верно?
у меня  два скрипта 
 /usr/bin/php bitrix/1c_exchange_metrika_fon_import.php
/usr/bin/php bitrix/1c_exchange_metrika_fon_offers.php

Comment: выглядит похоже на правду, пробелы вокруг `&&` только поставьте для переносимости

Comment: ну и протестируйте сперва на каких-нибудь проверочных php-скриптах (отправляющих вам два разных емейла, например), прежде чем в продакшн ставить

Comment: `command1 || true && command2` — а так не проще ли: `command1; command2`?

Comment: у меня так не получается,  даже не получается с одним файлом, куда я написала "hello world".

Comment: @AntonioK
0 1 * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /tmp/eshop-product-import.lock -c "cd /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/ && /usr/bin/php bitrix/1c_exchange_metrika_fon_import.php >> /tmp/eshop-product-import.log 2>&1"

не получается.....

Comment: укажите полный путь к файлу `bitrix/1c_exchange_metrika_fon_import.php`, а `cd` уберите

Comment: не получается так.

Comment: @RRR что "не получается"? ошибки какие? что делаете, что ожидаете, и чем результат отличается от ожидания?

Comment: Helloworld1(первый скрипт), Helloworld2(второй скрипт) не выводятся в один лог. Лог вообще не создается.
Вот мой код.
40 12 * * * /usr/bin/fsock -n /tmp/rrr.lock -c " /usr/bin/php /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.php ; /usr/bin/php /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script2.php  >> /tmp/rrr.log 2>&1"

Comment: кусок `" /usr/bin/php /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.php ; /usr/bin/php /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script2.php >> /tmp/rrr.log 2>&1"` замените на `" /usr/bin/php /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.php >> /tmp/rrr.log 2>&1 ;  /usr/bin/php /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script2.php >> /tmp/rrr.log 2>&1"`

Answer (score 1):

а зачем столько сложностей?

просто пишите скрипт `любоеимя.sh`

в теле пишешь по очереди се скрипты которые нужно запустить

и в крон помещаешь ну например `0 10 * * * любоеимя.sh`

и все

Comment: спасибо,  как писать;
#!/bin/bash
include_once(путь script1.php);
include_once( путь script2.php);
верно?