# Выполнение большого количества php-скриптов по очереди

Tags: php, очередь

уважаемые!
Есть некоторое количество PHP-скриптов, который отрабатывают разное количество времени (некоторые 2сек, некоторые 2 минуты). Нужно запустить один скрипт через CRON, который по очереди будет выполнять их (по мере загрузки страницы). Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "2suite.php";</script>';   в первом ставишь в конце ссылку во втором коде на 3 и тд, а первый запускаешь с крона )

Comment: Поочередное выполнение php-скриптов в cron https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473183/Поочередное-выполнение-php-скриптов-в-cron

Answer (score 0):

Использовать функцию sleep или unsleep для формирования нужной задержки в очереди

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php

Установить таймаут выполнения скрипта на нужное время что бы вся последовательность отработала верно

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php

выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
...
require_once 'your_script.php';
sleep('1');
require_once 'your_script2.php';
....
```

А там уже вам виднее, хоть курлом стучите по нему